# Nginx, deny access to certain url

Tags: nginx, security, php-fpm

I have a url shortening website. The url shortening is done by PHP. I need to restrict access to certain urls. This means certain url should be blacklisted for shortening. Is there any server side directives that can be used to restrict these url. Server is Nginx with PHP-FPM proxy.

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/568821/enable-post-value-in-nginx-access-log

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($arg_url = http://www.google.com/) { return 403; }
```